# How can I list ONLY open ports in a range with nc

Tags: networking, nc

I see many examples for nc, even one in the man page, that says

```
nc -zv 77.77.77.77 10-30
```

would report the open ports in the range 10-30. However, on my machine all the closed ports are also reported, so when I use a large range to check if any ports are open I am flooded with "connection refused" messages.

Why is the behavior on my machine different?

Should I simply filter away the verbose outut, or is there a way to let nc report only open ports?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

using grep

```
nc -zv 77.77.77.77 1-9000 2>&1 | grep succeeded
```